# Inequality between radius and diameter in graph $G$ [Diestel's book]

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

This is an excerpt from Diestel's book.  Let me remind you that $\text{diam}(G):=\max \limits_{x,y\in V} d_G(x,y)$.

I was able to show that $\text{rad}(G)\leq \text{diam}(G)$ and it was quite straightforward (we just need to consider two cases: when any two vertices are joined by a path and there are two vertices for which $d_G(x,y)=\infty$).

I have some difficulties with $\text{diam}(G)\leq 2\text{rad}(G)$.

1. Suppose that for any $x,y\in V$ we have $d_G(x,y)<\infty$. Then it is sufficient to show that for any $u,v,x\in V$ we can find $y_0\in V$ such that $d_G(u,v)\leq 2d_G(x,y_0)$. Then I stuck.
2. The case when $\exists x_0,y_0\in V$ with $d_G(x_0,y_0)=\infty$ also give me some issues.

I would be thankful if someone can show the proof. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be one or more central vertices for any graph (otherwise there is no radius).  Choose one and call it $z$.

For any $x,y\in V$ the triangle inequality gives $d_G(x,y) \le d_G(x,z)+d_G(z,y) \le \text{rad}(G)+\text{rad}(G)$.

This implies $\text{diam}(G)=\max \limits_{x,y\in V} d_G(x,y) \le 2\,\text{rad}(G)$.

Comment: Sorry but you said "there will be one or more central vertices for any graph (otherwise there is no radius)". Can you explain it please? It is not clear to me at all to be honest.

Comment: @ZFR You have defined the radius of the graph in terms of $\min$ and $\max$  so there must be at least one $z$ such that for all $y$ you have $d_G(z,y) \le \text{rad}(G)$ and for at least one $y$  you have $d_G(z,y) = \text{rad}(G)$.  So that $z$ will do here.  I suppose you might also want to consider the empty graph, but that is a trivial case.

Comment: Something is wrong with your formula in the above comment

Comment: @ZFR better now?

Comment: Sure! Let me read what you wrote more carefully.

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused. The definition of radius with double min and max seems a bit confusing. I cannot see why $\exists z$ s.t. $\forall y$ we have $d(z,y)\leq \text{rad}(G)$. And also the second statement

Comment: The only thing which I see from the definition of radius is that for any $u\in V$ we have that $\text{rad}(G)\leq \max \limits_{v\in V}d_G(u,v)$

Comment: You have the definition $\text{rad}(G)  = \min\limits_{x \in V(G)}  \max\limits_{y \in V(G)} d_G(x,y)$ so there is a particular $x$ that achieves the minimum (call it $z$) such that  $\text{rad}(G)  =\max\limits_{y \in V(G)} d_G(z,y)$ and this implies $d_G(z,y) \le \text{rad}(G) $ for all  $y \in V(G)$

Comment: Oh I see that is because we are always taking min or max over finite sets, right?

Comment: This reasoning is when radius is finite, right? If radius is infinite then diameter automatically is $\leq \infty$, right?

Comment: @ZFR The use of $\max$ suggests a finite graph: there are infinite graphs with no $\max d_G(x,y)$.  $\min$ is slightly less of an issue (a subset of non-negative integers and $+\infty$ will always have a minimum).  If either of the radius or diameter are infinite then other is too  and the inequalities become incomparable but irrelevant

Comment: Just want to be sure: we need to prove two inequalities. For the first one, i.e. $\text{rad}(G)\leq \text{diam}(G)$ we consider two cases. If diameter is $\infty$ the we are done. If diameter $<\infty$ then obvious from definition. For the second one, i.e. $\text{diam}(G)\leq 2\text{rad}(G)$ we also consider two cases: If $\text{rad}(G)=\infty$ then nothing to prove. In the case when $\text{rad}(G)<\infty$ we apply your reasoning. Right?

Comment: If you want to look at this that way

Comment: The vertex $z\in V(G)$ which has the property $\max \limits_{y\in V(G)}d_G(z,y)=\text{rad}(G)$ is called central, right?

Comment: Any such vertex is central according to your original definition.  Non-central vertices have $\max \limits_{y\in V(G)}d_G(x,y)>\text{rad}(G)$

Comment: Actually I do not see the definition of a central vertex. The author says if its greatest distance from any other vertex is as small as possible. But I cannot understand what does it mean?

Comment: "A vertex is central in $G$ if its greatest distance from any other vertex is as small as possible" is the same as "a vertex $z\in V(G)$ which has the property $\max \limits_{y\in V(G)}d_G(z,y)=\min \limits_{x\in V(G)}\max \limits_{y\in V(G)}d_G(x,y)$"